# CLI Extract date/time stamp (timestamp) from quicktime or mpeg files

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime, multimedia, mpeg

Is there a way to extract a date/time or a timestamp from various multi-media container files with Quicktime or MPEG2/MPEG4? I'm looking ideally for a command line tool. I have been able to get timestamps using `ffprobe`, part of the `ffmpeg` suite, but I haven't gotten the year, month and date. The camera had a clock so I'm pretty sure that this information was available.

The history of this data file is that it was first shot on miniDV and transferred to a Mac over Firewire 800 using QuicktimePlayer to record the video. I'm told that the miniDV format is motion jpeg. The `file` command reports that the file is `ISO Media, Apple QuickTime movie, Apple QuickTime (.MOV/QT)`.

```
% ffprobe -f lavfi -i "movie=filename.mov,fps=fps=25[out0]" -show_frames -show_streams -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time -of csv=p=0 2>&1 | head -30
ffprobe version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-librsvg --enable-libtheora --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libmodplug --enable-libvpx --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-lzma --enable-gnutls --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --disable-libjack --disable-libopencore-amrnb --disable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-libxcb --disable-libxcb-shm --disable-libxcb-xfixes --disable-indev=jack --enable-opencl --disable-outdev=xv --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-videotoolbox --enable-sdl2 --disable-securetransport --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/clang --arch=x86_64 --enable-x86asm --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'movie=/Volumes/SanDiskSSD/Movies/Italy22.mov,fps=fps=25[out0]':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
0.000000
0.040000
0.080000
0.120000
0.160000
0.200000
0.240000
0.280000
0.320000
0.360000
0.400000
0.440000
0.480000
0.520000
0.560000
%
```

I want output showing the year, month and date that this was shot.

Comment: The information probably does not exist in these miniDV files. You may have timecode, but it's default (at least at the time of miniDV) was to record "continuous" timecode: starting at 0 at the start of the tape. Professionals sometimes changed that to record real time, but usually only the time. There are "userbits" in a separate field of the timecode, and these could be set to record a date. But these userbits were generally ignored by the users as well as by the programs ingesting the material.

Comment: In some cases, however, there is a "recorded date" field in Quicktime metadata. `mediainfo` shows it on some old files of mine.

Comment: You don't want the frame or packet presentation timestamps, which are unrelated to the recorded datestamp which is simply a single string metadata field. In any case, fps filter will destroy existing timestamps and generate new ones. If the date metadata exists, you can get it via `ffprobe file -show_entries format_tags`

Comment: I think @Gyan suggestion is the best for you to follow if you are to use ffmpeg since he is part of the development team at ffmpeg. I would also suggest maybe you look at mediainfo.

Answer (score 2):

since you were able to get the timestamp, then you can use something like this

```
ffmpeg -y -i name.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontsize=36:fontcolor=blue:text='%{pts\:gmtime\:1675556887\:%A, %d, %B %Y %I\\\:%M\\\:%S %p}'" -preset ultrafast -f mp4 output.mp4
```

Remember to change this part `gmtime\:1575556887` to the already gotten timestamps

Comment: Are you sure about that command line? It is giving me an error and it also looks like you are telling it to draw the timestamp on the frame.  And I don't have timestamps: I have time *offsets* from the beginning of the tape, not from the beginning of time. Are you saying that UTC or GMT time is not actually stored on the video stream, even though the camera had a clock in it?.

Answer (score 0):

On some old DV Quicktime files I have, [mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) shows a "Recorded date" in it's "General" section:

> ```
> General
>  Complete name                            : /path/to/some-dv.mov
>  Format                                   : QuickTime
>  Format/Info                              : Original Apple specifications
>  Commercial name                          : DVCAM
>  File size                                : 125 MiB
>  Duration                                 : 34 s 520 ms
>  Overall bit rate                         : 30.4 Mb/s
>  Recorded date                            : 2008-03-16 16:50:46.000
>  Encoded date                             : UTC 2010-03-31 16:20:48
>  Tagged date                              : UTC 2010-03-31 16:21:25
>  Writing library                          : Apple QuickTime
>  Media/UUID                               : E70E5054-029E-42DE-A25F-7739BCBD7D0A
> ```

ffprobe/ffmpeg seem to only show the Encoded/Tagged dates, and don't show this "Recorded date".

Note that even `mediainfo` only shows this field on recent versions. Version 18.12-2
on Debian 9 shows it, but version 0.7.82-1 on Ubuntu 16.04 does not.

Comment: Alas, mediainfo shows me the date that I copied it from the camera to the computer, note the date that the camera recorded it.

Comment: Too bad. It may depend on the camera or the transfer program used. In my case, the copy date seems to be the "Encoded date", and the "Recording date" seems right. I had used Final Cut Pro 6 or 7.

Comment: The information you are looking for just does not exist in the file (MOV stores when it was recorded to MOV and not from the camera, and the raw content does not contain any date). You need to get the real DV input (usually DV has the recorded date), not the uncompressed content as you get. If you can not get the input, no luck, recording date is just lost. Jérôme, developer of MediaInfo.